# Crystal Report adding a year or month based on IF condition

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I am trying to add a year to currentdate in Crystal Reports after a `if` condition (if a user renews a month it will add a month, a year it will add a year to current date), but it's not working. I created a date field type and in formula editor I put the below formula I tried the below

```
If {tblcustomers_1.Customertypeofpay}="yearly" then DateAdd("yyyy", 1, CurrentDate)) else 
DateAdd("mm", 1, CurrentDate))
```

I tried so many ways for date add and still not working please help.

Comment: Does it work if you put a literal date instead of `CurrentDate`?

Comment: it says a date is required here when i used the below code

```
If {tblcustomers_1.Customertypeofpay}="yearly" then DateAdd("yyyy", 1, "7/2/2021") else 
DateAdd("yyyy", 1, "7/2/2021")

```

Answer (score 1):

Change it to:

```
If {tblcustomers_1.Customertypeofpay}="yearly" then 
DateAdd("yyyy", 1, CurrentDate) else DateAdd("m", 1, CurrentDate)
```

You had extra ')' and extra 'm'.

Comment: it says now a number or currency is required here.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked i had some mistakes

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, your typeofpay field is numeric rather than text.